# Prevent MATLAB from changing Java Look and Feel

Tags: java, matlab, look-and-feel

I have an application written in C++ that uses Java as the GUI. I interface with the native code using JNI. I call those "frontend" (Java GUI) and "backend" (C++ app). The backend is using some other libraries and one of them is a MATLAB shared library. When I initiliaze the MATLAB library by calling `mclInitializeApplication`, it changes the Look and Feel to the system one. Even when I change it back to Metal, there are some differences in font styles and such.

I know MATLAB is using Java to do its GUI stuff. But the library I am using is just some computations, I don't need any MATLAB GUI. How should I tell Matlab not to change the LaF or start its own JVM?

Answer (score 2):

I've never actually done what it looks like you are doing, but it looks like you want to pass in a `-nojvm` flag when you use mclInitializeApplication.  Some links below:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/mclinitializeapplication.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f8-4994.html

Comment: Unfortunately that is only for UNIX environment. I am on Windows.